# Перекрасить определённый элемент списка при получении определённой метки

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Задача такая: я получаю данные из базы данных, из этих данных формирую список с заголовком. Некоторые элементы содержат определённую метку, если эта метка встречается, необходимо фон ячейки элемента покрасить красным цветом, как только это будет сделано, эту метку надо удалить.

Метка выглядит так: "^^^", в массиве они выглядят так: (^^^4, ^^^N)

Никак не могу понять как это сделать, пока что смог только покрасить весь список целиком.
Использую фраемворк VueJS.

Попытался реализовать так:

Но таким методом закрашивается весь список целиком + поиск по массиву выполняется строго, а нужно что бы только по этим трём символам, я думаю, что нужно как то передать индекс элемента, но никак это сделать не могу правильно.

Может быть легче будет сменить саму метку на что то другое?

```js
.then(response => {
  (this.queries = response.data);
  this.tier = this.queries.TIER;
  var length = this.tier.length;
  var s = '^^^2';
  this.arr = this.tier.filter(function(item, i, arr) {
    return item.indexOf(s) > -1;
  });
  if (this.tier.indexOf(s) > -1) {
    this.errorClass = 'bg-danger';
  }
  console.log(this.arr);
})
```

```html
<td>
  <template v-if="arr != 0">
    <li
      v-for="(query, index) in queries.TIER"
      class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pointer"
      v-bind:class="[errorClass]"
    >
    {{ index }} : {{ query }}
    </li>
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    <li
      v-for="query in queries.TIER"
      class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pointer"
    >
    {{ query }}
    </li>
  </template>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    values: ['1', '2', '^^^3', '4']
  },
  methods: {
    isMarked: function(value) {
      return !(value.indexOf('^^^') < 0);
    },
    format: function(value) {
      const index = value.indexOf('^^^');
      if (index < 0) {
        return value;
      }
      
      return value.substring(0, index) + value.substring(index + 3);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.marked {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="value in values" v-bind:class="{ marked: isMarked(value) }">{{ format(value) }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, всё работает

Answer (score 1):

Мой вариант решения.
Примечания: всегда используйте key в v-for и data должна быть функцией

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      values: ['1', '2', '^^^3', '4']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    format: val => val.includes('^^^') ? val.slice(3) : val
  }
})
```

```css
.marked {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li 
      v-for="value in values" 
      :key="'my-item' + value"
      :class="{ marked: value.includes('^^^') }"
    >
      {{ format(value) }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Окей, спасибо за совет